# DateTime parse with custom format

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse a datetime value using this:

```
DateTime insertedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1], "yyyy-MM-dd mm:hh:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

//tokens[0] = 2013-09-05 
//tokens[1] = 07:23:32
```

I am getting this error:

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should write:

```
DateTime insertedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1], "yyyy-MM-dd mm:HH:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

because `hh` means 12h time and `HH` means 24h time and putting 23 as hour in 12h time is invalid :)

Of course if you are sure that hours are second in your time and you don't want to write `HH:mm:ss` or `hh:mm:ss` (for 12h format)

[**DEMO here**](http://ideone.com/8l8YM9)

Comment: The hour needs to be put before the minute.

Comment: @shahkalpesh and what I wrote in comment after 'Of course' ? Have you read whole post? My code works fine, so downvoting is not fair

Comment: My apologies. I cant cancel the downvote, you get the upvote. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Hours should go first: `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`

NOTE: Consider to use 24-hour `HH` format instead of 12-hour `hh` format.

Comment: Are you sure it can determine **a.m.** versus **p.m.** with the given information? Maybe he meant `HH`, not `hh`, as mentioned in other answer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen by default it will be AM. But you are right - if OP needs PM time he should also use *HH* instead of *hh*. Or add *tt* to format and provide AM/PM designator

Answer (score 3):

You should change your `mm:hh:ss` to `hh:mm:ss` because you giving string hour part first.

```
DateTime insertedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(2013-09-05 07:23:32, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(insertedDateTime);
```

Output will be;

```
9/5/2013 7:23:32 AM
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/z1VtgT).

For more informations;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

try to use

```
string strdate= "yourdate";
DateTime.ParseExact(strdate, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This won't work. Did you tried it first before you answered here?

Comment: yes i used before it work fine you need to make sure string date format